# gridstack margin width not set -- items touch each other on each row

Tags: css, gridstack

I am using gridstack for the first time and I am having trouble with the horizontal margins.  Clearly there is something in my css that is making my items too wide.

I see in the demos that gridstack.css has left and right set  at 10px each, and I am using that same default css.

I have set gridstack up to use 6 columns as follows:

```
<div id="container" class="grid-stack grid-stack-6"> 
  <div class="grid-stack-item"
    data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0"
    data-gs-width="3" data-gs-height="2">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
        <i class="icon-lock-open pinDiv warning"></i>
        <i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i>
        PRE MAP
  </div>
 <div class="grid-stack-item lockAspect"
    data-gs-x="3" data-gs-y="0"
    data-gs-width="3" data-gs-height="2">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="background:pink;">
        <i class="icon-lock pinDiv warning"></i>
        <i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i>
        POST MAP
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the following options:

```
DEFAULT_GRIDSTACK_OPTIONS =  {
    cellHeight: 150,
    verticalMargin: 10,
    width: 6
};
```

and I am including gridstack-extra as well as gridstack.css.

Why do my items have no horizontal margin at all?

thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

i haved same problem. I fixed

```
.grid-stack > .grid-stack-item > .grid-stack-item-content{
   left: 3px;
   right: 3px;
}
```

But not best practices, i want config in javascript similar config option verticalMargin

```
var optionsLayoutDesign = {
            width: 6,
            float: true,
            removable: '.trash',
            verticalMargin:6,
            cellHeight:50,
            removeTimeout: 200,
            acceptWidgets: '.grid-stack-item',
            animate :true,
        };
$('#layout-design').gridstack(optionsLayoutDesign);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to style the class

`grid-stack-item-content`

instead of

`grid-stack-item`